# Google Translate Documents php text

Tags: php, regex, notepad++, google-translate

I'd like to run thousands of php language keys through Google Translate Documents on https://translate.google.com. The text looks like this:

```
$lang['activate_deactivate'] = "Activate / Deactivate";
$lang['invalid_username'] = "Invalid username";
$lang['you_must_enter_username'] = "You must enter username";
$lang['invalid_user_name'] = "Invalid username";
$lang['user_deactivated'] = "User has been deactivated";
$lang['user_not_deactivated'] = "User could not be deactivated";
```

However I don't want to translate anything between [ and ]. So far I've tried wrapping it in span notranslate tags, capitalizing every word but neither of those worked.

An idea I do have is somehow adding an uncommon character such as █ after every letter between [ and ] then just removing all after the translation, I'm not sure how to perform that with regex. "(?<=[).*?(?=])" will find the text I need but I'm not sure how to replace it to insert the character after each letter.

Or if anyone has any better ideas, I'd love to hear them. Thanks.

Comment: Are all language keys in one file? All keys have an underscrore? I copied your test data into a single text file and translated it into German using the link provided. As a clean result (with the known translation errors of Google), only the text parts in quotation marks were translated. Where is the problem?

Comment: Several files, with hundreds of lines. Not every line has a problem but many do. Not all keys have an underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Notepad++ you might use:

```
(?:\[|\G(?!^))\K[^][](?=[^][]*])
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[` Match `[`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, but not at the start of the string to get consecutive separate matches
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\K` Forget what is matched until now
- `[^][]` Match a single char other than `[` and `]`
- `(?=[^][]*])` Assert a closing `]` to the right

Replace with the full match followed by the character that you want `$0█`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/flYMQe/1).

[image]